# Bullets are not showing up across network client screen in game

Tags: java, networking, 2d

Hi all so I a tank war game thats ran over a network and is multiplayer, however whenever I fire a bullet it shows on my screen but not the other player's screen. Can you help, here's a snippet of code form where i think the problem is coming from:

```
class Tank implements Ball {

double locX, locY, radius, angle;
int self; // index of this tank in WarPanel.tanks
public boolean turnL, turnR, forth, back, fire;
boolean prevtL, prevtR, prevfo;
Color color;
Image image;

public static final double twoPi = Math.PI * 2.0;
public static final double turnRate = Math.PI / 8;
public static final double speed = 4.0;
public static final int RELOAD = 8; // delay between bullets
int count; // timer for reloading

public static final int MAXBULLETS = 7; // max simultaneous shots
Bullet bullets[] = new Bullet[MAXBULLETS];

AffineTransform saveAT; // place to hold current affine transform

public Tank(double x, double y, double a, int index, Image im){
    locX = x;
    locY = y;
    angle = a;
    self = index;
    image = im;
    radius = 22;
    // create bullets for this tank
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++)
        bullets[i] = new Bullet(self);
}

public double getX() { return locX; }
public double getY() { return locY; }
public double getRadius() { return radius; }
public boolean isAlive() { return true; }

void update(Boolean local) {
    if (turnL)
        turnLeft(turnRate);
    if (turnR)
        turnRight(turnRate);
    if (forth){
        moveForward();
        // Check for rocks
        if (WarPanel.hitAnItem(this, WarPanel.rocks) >= 0)
            backUp();
    }
    if (local){
        if (turnL != prevtL){
          WarPanel.send("turnL "+turnL+" "+locX+" "+locY+" "+angle);
          prevtL = turnL;
        }
        if (turnR != prevtR){
          WarPanel.send("turnR "+turnR+" "+locX+" "+locY+"   "+angle);
          prevtR = turnR;
        }
        if (forth != prevfo){
          WarPanel.send("forth "+forth+" "+locX+" "+locY+" "+angle);
          prevfo = forth;
        }
    }
    if (fire){
        fireBullet();
    }
    // Update all of our bullets
    for (Bullet b: bullets)
        b.update();
}

public void processMove(String s){
    // Update movement parameters based on s
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    // Get the flag change
    String command = sc.next();
    boolean value = sc.nextBoolean();
    if (command.equals("turnL"))
        turnL = value;
    else if (command.equals("turnR"))
        turnR = value;
    else if (command.equals("forth"))
        forth = value;
    else
        System.out.println("Unexpected move: "+command);
    // then unpack position update
    locX = sc.nextDouble();
    locY = sc.nextDouble();
    angle = sc.nextDouble();
}

void paint(Graphics g){
    // Use the affine transform feature in Graphics2D
    // to easily rotate the tank's image.
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    saveAT = g2.getTransform();
    g2.translate(locX, locY);
    g2.rotate(angle);
    g2.drawImage(image, (int)(-radius), (int)(-radius), null);
    // Reset the transform (this is important)
    g2.setTransform(saveAT);
    // Then draw bullets
    for (Bullet b: bullets)
        b.paint(g2);

}

void fireBullet(){
    // If it has been long enough since the last shot...
    count--;
    if (count > 0) return;
    // ...and if all the bullets aren't currently in use...
    int slot = getAvailableBullet();
    if (slot < 0)
        return;
    // ...then launch a new bullet
    bullets[slot].setLocation(locX, locY);
    bullets[slot].setDirection(angle);
    bullets[slot].reset();
    // Reset the timer
    count = RELOAD;
}

int getAvailableBullet(){
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++)
        if (!bullets[i].isAlive())
            return i;
    return -1;
}

void turnRight(double a){
    angle += a;
    if (angle > twoPi)
        angle -= twoPi;
}

void turnLeft(double a){
    angle -= a;
    if (angle < 0.0)
        angle += twoPi;
}

void moveForward(){
    locX += speed*Math.cos(angle);
    locY += speed*Math.sin(angle);
}

void backUp(){
    locX -= speed*Math.cos(angle);
    locY -= speed*Math.sin(angle);
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that sends bullet state to the other player across the network?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for but Here is where I think it may reside    `public void processMove(String s){
   // Send command to tank not controlled by
   // this player
   tanks.get(1 - playerID).processMove(s);
  }


  public static int hitAnItem(Ball b, ArrayList<? extends Ball> c){
    for (Ball r: c){
     if (!r.isAlive())
      continue;
     double dx = b.getX() - r.getX();
     double dy = b.getY() - r.getY();
     double bound = b.getRadius() + r.getRadius();
     if ((dx*dx + dy*dy) < (bound*bound))
      return c.indexOf(r);
    }
    return -1;
 }`